# Send and recieve json between android and php webservices - force close

Tags: android

I am trying for sending data from my Android App and receiving output according to input. But application force closed as soon as i click on button. 
Here is my code for java file in android:

```
package com.example.diary;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    private EditText value;
    private Button btn;
    private ProgressBar pb;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        value=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        pb=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(value.getText().toString().length()<1){

                        // out of range
                        Toast.makeText(this, "please enter something", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{
                        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        new MyAsyncTask().execute(value.getText().toString());      
                    }

    }
    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{

        @Override
        protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            postData(params[0]);
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Code Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
            pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
        }
        public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/remoteaccess/index.php");
            //HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.13/educlinic/Widget/AndroidApp");
            try {

                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myHttpData", valueIWantToSend));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

                //This is the response from a php application
                String reverseString = response;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "response" + reverseString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CPE response " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "IOE response " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                }
        }

}}
```

and this is code for xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" 
        android:id="@+id/text1"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is for php:

```
<?php
$data = $_POST['myHttpData'];
 echo $data;
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: share log cat output .

Comment: post your logcat trace here..so that we can help you with better solutions.

Comment: 03-15 10:25:09.307: I/Choreographer(3738): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-15 10:25:57.087: I/Choreographer(3738): Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-15 10:26:37.807: I/Process(3738): Sending signal. PID: 3738 SIG: 9
03-15 10:26:47.737: E/Trace(3822): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-15 10:26:48.867: D/gralloc_goldfish(3822): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most probably you are getting following error:

> RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not
>   called Looper.prepare()

inside `postData` method you are trying to show Toast's.but you are calling `postData`  method from non UI Thread (from doInBackground method of AsyncTask).

just remove Toast's  from `postData` method or use `onPostExecute` to access or update UI elements

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now in spite of displaying output is toast, I have used textview. when I am debugging this, same is shown but not shown at runtime.

Comment: @NehaMangla : im not getting u problem is solved or still facing any issue ?

Comment: Do not use a TextView either. Use Log().

Comment: @NehaMangla : plz add your latest code with question and also explain problem which u are facing currently with current code. if this answer help you in solving current issue then mark it as answer.Thanks

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I have solved the problem by creating one more thread.